# GBM and Caret package: invalid number of intervals

Tags: r, r-caret, gbm

Though I am defining that `target <- factor(train$target, levels = c(0, 1))`, the below-given code provides this error:

> Error in cut.default(y, unique(quantile(y, probs = seq(0, 1, length =
>   cuts))),  :    invalid number of intervals In addition: Warning
>   messages: 1: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :   cannnot
>   compute class probabilities for regression

What does it mean and how to fix this?

```
  gbmGrid <- expand.grid(n.trees = (1:30)*10, 
                         interaction.depth = c(1, 5, 9), 
                         shrinkage = 0.1)

  fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                             number = 5, 
                             repeats = 5, 
                             verboseIter = FALSE, 
                             returnResamp = "all",
                             classProbs = TRUE)

  target <- factor(train$target, levels = c(0, 1)) 

  gbm <- caret::train(target ~ .,
                      data = train,
                      #distribution="gaussian",
                      method = "gbm",
                      trControl = fitControl,
                      tuneGrid = gbmGrid)

  prob = predict(gbm, newdata=testing, type='prob')[,2]
```

Comment: What is `train` in `target <- factor(train$target,...)`?

Comment: Try adding `summaryFunction = twoClassSummary ` in your `trainControl` function and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't do this:

```
 target <- factor(train$target, levels = c(0, 1))
```

You will get an warning:

> At least one of the class levels are not valid R variables names; This may cause errors if class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to: X0, X1

Second, you created an object called `target`. Using the formula method means that `train` will use the column called `target` in the data frame `train` and those are different data. Modify the column.